# How to compare two Azure (release) pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I made a copy of an Azure (release) pipeline, and after some (deep) changes, I would like to compare it to the original one, to apply back those changes.

It looks like there is no automated comparison tool, and the only way I have, is to export the json definition.

Unfortunately, the two Json definitions are not comparable line by line, because arrays of subojects are in some way 'scrambled', in the two files, and don't correspond each other...

Am I the first to have this problem? :-)

Thanks in advance.
A

Comment: I don't think you have another option... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to compare two Azure (release) pipelines?

There is a **History** tab you can see a list of changes that includes who made the change , when the change occurred and modified content.

To get the detailed info,  click `...`, and then click **Compare Difference** or **Revert Pipeline**:

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work on two different pipelines. I know that I could work through all the changes in the pipeline... :-)

Comment: Thinking better, it's also true that I can compare the first and the last version where I made changes I'm interested in, and see all of them together: hence I will accept this solution. I expected this to be a common problem, for which there was some better solution...

Comment: I have to explain better the 'general' problem: I have a pipeline, and I duplicate it to 'try' something different. Meanwhile, someone else modifies the original one. If I'm satisfied with my changes, I want to merge them back to the original one. In Build pipelines I can 'yaml' them, and use a normal version control (git?). In release pipeline there's not still any version control, that would just solve this problem.

Comment: Where I work, we have a need to compare all of the PROD build pipelines, not to themselves, but to a baseline standard.  We want to make sure that expected pipeline elements are present in each, identify pipelines that do not meet the expected standard, and also need a way to express said standard.  Was pursuing YAML GREP and YAML DIFF, and that is the approach we're currently pointing towards.